# creating the object as static for the class

Tags: c#-4.0

I have created a  class in class library  called "Exam" in c#.net. And in my windows form I create a object like "

```
static Exam obj= new Exam();
```

1. What will happen?
2. Can I able to reinitialize this object by using new operator?
3. If I   reinitialize this object, whether  new memory will be allocated or the same memory  will be used?
4. How can I destroy this object, because since it is static the object will be available till the application closed?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It would be helpful if you give solution for my about question. I don't want to use static class here.

Answer (score 0):

We will practically use it when we should allow only one instance to be created for a class(singleton).

say

```
 public class Exam
    {
        private static Exam exam = null;

        public string Id { get; set; }


        public static Exam getInstance()
        {

            if (exam == null)
            {
                exam = new Exam();
                exam.Id = IdGenerator.GenerateId();
            }

            return exam;
        }
    }
```

//CALLER

```
Exam exam = Exam.getInstance();

                Console.WriteLine(exam.Id);

                Exam exam2 = Exam.getInstance();

                Console.WriteLine(exam2.Id);
```

//though you create two instances, chech the Ids of both.. they look similar.

//this instance will be available till the application's exit.

Hope this answers your questions